# how to change cell color depending on values in php

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

This is the table that I'm using for receiving the data, I want that the Balance 1 and 2 assign a 3 types of color (red, yellow and green) based on the values, for example; I want to assign that the color red has to be assign when the value is <= 0, yellow when >= 1 && <=5 and green when the value is > 5

EDIT(I dont want to add another to show the color without the data inserted)

```
                    <td><b><?php echo $row ['part_number'] ?></b></td>
                    <td><b><?php echo date("M d, Y | h:i:s a",strtotime($row['datet'])) ?></b></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row ['description'] ?></td>
                    <td><b><?php echo $row ['max_1'] ?></b></td>
                    <td><b><?php echo $row ['min_1'] ?></b></td>
                    <td><b><?php echo $row ['stock_1'] ?></b></td>
                    <td><b><?php echo $row ['balance_1'] ?></b></td>
                    <?php echo "<td style='background-color:".(($row['balance_1'] < 1000) ? '#FF0000;' : '#FFFF00')."'></td>"; ?>
                    <td><b><?php echo $row ['max_2'] ?></b></td>
                    <td><b><?php echo $row ['min_2'] ?></b></td>
                    <td><b><?php echo $row ['stock_2'] ?></b></td>
                    <td><b><?php echo $row ['balance_2'] ?></b></td>
                    <?php echo "<td style='background-color:".(($row['balance_2'] < 1000) ? '#FF0000;' : '#FFFF00')."'></td>"; ?>
```

Comment: Would a [simple function](https://3v4l.org/8mYiD) solve this? Otherwise I'm not sure on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a class on each case:

```
if ($row['balance_1'] <= 0) {
   <td class="red"><b><?php echo $row ['balance_1'] ?></b></td>
} else if ($row['balance_1'] >= 1 && $row['balance_1'] <= 5) {
   <td class="yellow"><b><?php echo $row['balance_1'] ?></b></td>
} else if ($row['balance_1'] > 5) {
   <td class="green"><b><?php echo $row['balance_1'] ?></b></td>
}
```

And in your css:

```
.red {
   background-color: #FF0000
}
.yellow {
   background-color: #FFFF00;
}
.green {
   background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but where do I have to put it and what I have to replace the if statement

Comment: @Antonio do you want to change the background-color of the balance_1 and balance_2 rows in the table?

Comment: I just implemented the code that you gave me and It works perfectly, thank you so much man <3

Comment: Glad to hear that! u welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using echo to print the td, you can use it to just print the color in the style attribute based on some condition

In this example I'm using a div to showcase:

```
$balance = 1000;
<div style="background-color: <?php echo $balance > 1 ? '#FF0000;' : '#FFFF00;'?>">
    test
</div>
```

The div then looks like this:
[image: div]

I hope this can guide you forward :)